# Undo `mount --rbind /dev ./chroot/dev`

Tags: mount, chroot, umount

I've executed `mount --rbind /dev ./chroot/dev` for using in chroot'ed environment.

Then I wanted to unmount it and executed `umount ./chroot/dev` but it fails with error:

```
umount: ..../chroot/dev: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

Seems it doesn't matter which Linux I use, doesn't matter do I use `./chroot/dev` or not.

Any suggestions how to undo `mount --rbind` in such case?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549945/how-do-i-unmount-dev-after-mounting-it) answer.

Comment: @SimonSudler Sorry, I was inattentive. It helped!